# Using diodes to wire a battery pack in series and parallel for different voltages

Tags: voltage, batteries, split

This is my first post on this site.
I have an EV design were I want 900V for a traction motor, but I need 450V for auxiliary equipment.

The first thing that came to mind is DC-DC converter, but it is expensive, and possibly has a notable power loss.

I thought about alternatives and about splitting up battery packs:
[image]

For example, lets say I need 36V for a BLDC motor, and 12V for a Arduino.
I use 3 12V batteries wired in series for 36V, and use diodes to wire them in parallel for the 12V.
The diodes stopping the batteries from shorting.

I know diodes have a considerable voltage drop, and for the EV application I would use ideal diodes. 
By using the diodes, all batteries should drain equally, avoiding the battery pack unbalancing. 
In the EV, the 12V batteries would be separate modules with their own monitoring.

Is this a crazy idea?
Would the battery explode for some reason?
And should I just use a DC-DC converter instead?

Comment: Not going to work. Your 12V supply here is 36V - 2 diode drops.

Comment: My bad, I switched up the + and - on the 36V.

Answer (score 1):

The diodes stop the batteries from shorting to each other, but they also deliver 36 V to your '12 V' output.

If your low voltage drain is very, very small, say less than 1% of the drain on the whole pack, then you could maybe supply it from one battery, and rely on the charger to rebalance the cells when you recharge.

Best to use a DC to DC converter running from the whole pack to generate your low voltage supplies.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. The diodes marked with an 'X' are reverse biased and do nothing.*

The output from this circuit will be 36 V. (Note that it's a good idea to give component designations so that we can refer to D1, etc. rather than "the third diode from the top".)

> ... and for the EV application I would use ideal diodes.

Ehm, you *do* realise that there is no such thing?

> By using the diodes, all batteries should drain equally, avoiding the battery pack unbalancing.

No, this won't work as explained above.

I don't think you're ready for 900 V work.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to the coast of the vehicle, a 36 VDC to 12 VDC converter is negligible, less than US$20 for [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0756WMHHR) found on a quick search. Not only will it drop the voltage, but t also ensures that there is not too much drain on one group of cells, so that charging can be more predictable.

You must also know the answer to some questions to know if this is suitable:

- Must the output be isolated, or can it share a common ground or B+?
- What is the current requirement?